# Automatically DROP FUNCTION when DROP TABLE on POSTGRESQL 11.7

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, drop

I'm trying to, somehow, trigger a automatic function drop when a table is dropped and I can't figure out how to do it.

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to trigger a function drop when a specific table is dropped? (POSTGRESQL 11.7)

---

**Detailed explanation**

I'll try to explain my problem using a simplified use case with dummy names.

1. I have three tables: ***sensor1, sensor2*** and ***sumSensors***;
2. A **FUNCTION** (*sumdata*) was created to **INSERT data on *sumSensors*** table. Inside this function I'll fetch data from *sensor1* and *sensor2* tables and insert its sum on table sumSensors;
3. A trigger was created for each sensor table which like this:

   **CREATE TRIGGER trig1 
       AFTER INSERT ON sensor1
       FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE
       FUNCTION sumdata();**
4. Now, when a **new row is inserted** on tables ***sensor1* OR *sensor2***, the function ***sumdata*** will be executed and ***insert the sum of last values from both on table sumSensors***

If I wanted to **`DROP FUNTION sumdata CASCADE;`**, the triggers would be automatically removed from tables *sensor1* and *sensor2*. Until now that's everything fine! But that's not what I want.

---

My problem is:

Q: And if I just **`DROP TABLE sumSensors CASCADE;`**? What would happen to the function which was meant to insert on this table?

A: As expected, since there's no association between sumSensors table and sumdata function, the **function won't be dropped** (still exist)! **The same happens to the triggers** which use it (still exist). This means that when a new row is inserted on sensor tables, the function sumdata will be **executed and corrupted, leading to a failure** (even the INSERT which triggered the function execution won't be actually inserted).

Is there a way to trigger a function drop when a specific table is dropped?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no dependency tracking for functions in PostgreSQL (as of version 12).

You can use [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html) to maintain the dependencies yourself.

Full example follows.

More information: [documentation of event triggers feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html), [support functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html).

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE _testtable ( id serial primary key, payload text );

INSERT INTO _testtable (payload) VALUES ('Test data');

CREATE FUNCTION _testfunc(integer) RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ SELECT $1 + count(*)::integer FROM _testtable; $$;

SELECT _testfunc(100);

CREATE FUNCTION trg_drop_dependent_functions()
RETURNS event_trigger 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    _dropped record;
BEGIN
    FOR _dropped IN
        SELECT schema_name, object_name
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()
        WHERE object_type = 'table'
    LOOP
        IF _dropped.schema_name = 'public' AND _dropped.object_name = '_testtable' THEN
            EXECUTE 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _testfunc(integer)';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_drop_dependent_functions ON sql_drop
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_drop_dependent_functions();

DROP TABLE _testtable;

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Awesome,  that solved my problem. Thanks a lot @filiprem, honestly!